# A space is compact if and only if every continuous function has compact support

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> $X$ is compact if and only if $C(X)=C_c(X)$.

(Here $C_c(X)$ is the space of continuous functions with compact support.)

I can prove one direction, $(\Leftarrow)$. Let $f\in C(X)$. We know that for any X, $C(x)\supset C_c(X)$. Then $f\in C_c(X)$. In particular this is true for $f(x)=1$, for which $\operatorname{supp}(f)=X$. Thus $X$ is compact.

But I don't understand how to do reverse.

Comment: What is $C_C$? Continous functions with compact support?

Answer (score 3):

The other direction: Suppose $X$ is compact, and $f \in C(X)$. As $\mathrm{supp}\, f$ is closed in $X$ and $X$ is compact, $\mathrm{supp}\, f$ is compact. Therefore $f \in C_c(X)$.